# I want to know if there is a solution that every time we upload the CSV file , it doesn't create new contacts and households

Tags: data, migration, npsp, data-migration, data-import-wizard

I'm trying to import a combined fully mapped CSV file on a Salesforce non-profit package with Data Import Wizard 
you know that we focus on 3 objects in this case : (households(account) , Donors(contact) and Opportunities(Donations) 
I want to know if there is a solution that every time we upload the CSV file , it doesn't create new contacts and households 
can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Can you put a picture of csv, which you are importing.

Comment: I attached a screen shot , does it help or do you need more details? 
the problem is if we use Add new record in date import wizard to import the new data into salesforce , a new record will be created for household and donor both then it makes so many troubles to merge them 
you may say the third option (add new or or update existing data ) works fine then can you guide me how to fill the drop down lists?

Comment: use data loader, rather the import wizard

Comment: Data loader is not suitable for this project

Answer (score 0):

Before you load the data, need to understand the relationship among those objects.

Opportunity is related to Account with M-D relationship.

Contact is related to Account with Lookup relationship.

> Before importing Opportunity, Account must exist in the system, otherwise you will get error during upload.

If Account record exist then you can directly point to the AccountId and load the Opportunities.

If you already have Account and Contact, and you need to insert only the Opportunity then use  [DataLoader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_loader.htm&type=0) and upload the data.

Refer [Import Data trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/data_management/units/data_import) and video for further information.

Comment: please take a look at this screen shot 
I don't know how do I fill the drop down lists to avoid creating new houshould and new contact or donner 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byotzv0TY-tEdk9QRHd3WVZEQ0U/view